# Xcode source path

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm working on a project with Xcode, and I'm rearranging all the source files. I see that Xcode, in the "Compile Sources" section in the target configuration, looks for all the source codes using a pathname relative to the project directory (PROJECT_DIR).

I have created a new folder where all the sources, libraries, and headers will go.  Is there a way to tell Xcode to look for sources from a user-defined directory so when I change the directory I won't have to re-add all the source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Xcode file inspector to modify the path. Here you can change the path of groups and file in your project structure.

Make sure all your files & groups are set `Relative to group`.
This way when you move files in group to a different location keeping their relative positions same, you can just change the group path from Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Great, but I need the file location to be relative to a specific folder, or at least that I can specify the full path with a project variable defined by me.

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it more clear how you can use location setting.

Comment: So with "Group" you're not meaning the virtual folders created in the Xcode project, are you? And how do I edit the group location?

Comment: yes, the yellow folders in project hierarchy are groups. The name below the location setting is the path of that group. You can use the small folder icon to change that.